# Last time word/office was used

Tags: command-line, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Where I work at we have (3k+ computers) that is 95% Windows 7, and for licensing reasons I need to figure which computers have office installed on them but haven't been used in the last 3 months. I need this scripted (I can write scripts) but I have no idea how to **find the last used date for office via the command line.** The last used date in control panel isn't showing any value.

Is this possible?

Comment: The problem is your question is asking when they last used Office, which contains more than a single program, some more likely to be used daily then others.

Comment: Either or, office is installed as suite which is how it shows up in control panel for our users. But determining last used for just  word and/or excel will also work since users rarely use anything else

Comment: But if they have used Outlook then you still need that license activated.

Comment: Event Viewer has Microsoft Office Alerts. I have Office 2013 installed. Can you refer to that?

Comment: Yes, event viewer could work. It looks like it records an event for errors/alerts that pop up to users. (IE: "We save a draft, want to keep it", "Want to save changes to document1" and many others)

Comment: Could you post the solution as an answer, rather than embedding it in the question?  That will be helpful to people coming to help and people searching solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an exact date, but I decided to recursively check the c:\users folder for any .doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx documents and check "Event viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft Office Alerts" for any events (sunk818).

I Found 300+ machines that don't need office and results appear to be 95% accurate.